# Wordpress Site in two different language and content on one domain

Tags: wordpress

I want to create website In Kurdish and Arabic Language on one domain, The Kurdish language is the default. But I want to Kurdish content different to the Arabic content. Means, I Don't want translate From Kurdish to Arabic or vise Versa by using WPML Plugin or any other plugins, I want each language has own content

How can I do this? I know that I need two different databases but how I can connect to these databases from one domain.?

Comment: i can custom code plugin for that

Comment: Help me how to can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to provide different content using Custom Post Types plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
You could provide different content based on `lang` parameter in URL. If person is browsing your website in selected language it will always be appended to the website URL as parameter. 
This functionality is already provided by other plugins, WPML as well.
Custom post type could look at this parameter and serve different content. You would need to apply changes in the THEME.

Comment: Thanks if WPML provide this option please explain to me how I can do this because I purchased WPML and installed on my site, I put the Kurdish language to default But when I click on the Arabic language redirect me to www.mysite.com/ar and not contains any content but how I can from dashboard add contents to it?

Comment: If you take a look in here: https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/ in section `Language URL format` you can see there are 3 options of declaring language of website. It could be the one you showed so a subpage, other domain or lang parameter. Just use the last option and you will be able to check in your URL if it works after applying.

Comment: Can you also explain how much different content you want to show in different languages ? Is this just text or HTML ?